# Oracle connection getting time out

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have an application which query database at a specific time of day and then it idle for next 3-4 hours and then again it queries database for some data but it is being executed only once and at the second attempt it is throwing an error.

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();
    OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    string sql = _query;
    command.CommandText = sql;

    OracleDataAdapter oAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, connection);
    oAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
    connection.Close();
    return myDataSet;
}
```

The Error is being thrown at:

```
oAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
```

And error stats as `ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel`

To my understanding connection should be disposed after one call and it should create another connection on each request. I have checked that the connection to the server is available and listening, no network issues while this error is occurring.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new `DataSet` instance of `myDataSet`?

Comment: Yes for a specific reason on each call i am creating a new instance for myDataSet.

Comment: Talk to your IT department, perhaps a firewall triggers some timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I got it, For any one else looking for answer is that I was calling `return myDataSet;` inside the using statement first i didn't notice it but as `OracleConnection` is being inherited from IDisposable and i was returning dataset inside using statement so it was never getting disposed off properly. so i just changed this from

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
{
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
connection.Open();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
string sql = _query;
command.CommandText = sql;
OracleDataAdapter oAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, connection);
oAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
connection.Close();
return myDataSet;}
```

to

```
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection()){
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
connection.Open();
OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
string sql = _query;
command.CommandText = sql;
OracleDataAdapter oAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, connection);
oAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
connection.Close(); }
return myDataSet;
```